# Spring AOP - Determine whether method was invoked by @Scheduled

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop, spring-scheduled

I have a runtime annotation @MyAnnotation, and I would like to write an Aspect that determines whether the test() method below was called by:

- Spring's @Scheduled framework
- normal method invocation

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "*/1 * * * * *") // scheduled to invoke every second
    @MyAnnotation
    public void test() {
        // business logic
    }
}
```

aspect code (pointcut + advice)

```
    @Around(value="@annotation(myAnnotation)")
    public Object featureToggle(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, MyAnnotation myAnnotation) throws Throwable {
        Boolean isInvoked = // TODO - is invoked by @Scheduled or not
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set the scheudle thread name prefix, then determine it by thread name.

```yaml
spring
  task:
    scheduling:
      thread-name-prefix: xxxx-scheduling-
```

```
@Aspect
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ScheduledTaskAspect {
    private final TaskSchedulingProperties taskSchedulingProperties;

    @Around(value="@annotation(myAnnotation)")
    public Object featureToggle(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, MyAnnotation myAnnotation) throws Throwable {
        String currentThreadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        Boolean isInvoked = currentThreadName.startsWith(taskSchedulingProperties.getThreadNamePrefix());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would like to achieve something like that:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class ScheduledTask {

    @Scheduled(cron = "0/1 * * * * *")
    @ScheduledTaskAnnotation(message = "ScheduledTaskMessage", number = 10)
    public void doAction() {
        log.debug("Task scheduled");
    }

}
```

```
@Slf4j
@Aspect
@Component
public class ScheduledTaskAspect {

    @Around("execution(public * *(..)) && @annotation(hu.gaszabo.sample.schedule.ScheduledTaskAnnotation)")
    public void logScheduledTaskAction(final ProceedingJoinPoint p) {
        log.debug("Aspect");

        parameters(p).ifPresent(a -> {
            log.debug("message: {}", a.message());
            log.debug("number: {}", a.number());
        });

        try {
            p.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Optional<ScheduledTaskAnnotation> parameters(final ProceedingJoinPoint p) {
        final Method method = ((MethodSignature) p.getSignature()).getMethod();
        return Optional.ofNullable(AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(method, ScheduledTaskAnnotation.class));
    }

}
```

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(value = { ElementType.METHOD })
public @interface ScheduledTaskAnnotation {

    String message() default "Message";

    long number() default 0L;

}
```

Comment: I don't see how the aspect knows whether the doAction was invoked via @Scheduled framework or by normal invocation.

Comment: All methods which match to expression (being public and have specific annotation) will be proxied objects. It does not know whether method invoked normally or scheduled way and I don't think it is relevant. If method matches to the expression then it executes AOP logic.

Comment: I see, sounds like what I am asking for is impossible :[.
I was thinking stacktrace could be of some help within the AOP logic

Comment: If you want AOP logic to be executed only if a method has Scheduled annotation then use this expression. `@Around("execution(public * *(..)) && @annotation(org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled)")`

Comment: I should have clarified. I have a single public method that is both: @Scheduled and also being invoked normally elsewhere. I want to be able to write an Aspect that could distinguish between those 2 invocations.

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting stack traces is always ugly, but of course you can do it:

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q65397019;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q65397019;

import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyComponent {
  @Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
//  @Async
  @MyAnnotation
  public void doSomething() {}
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q65397019;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
public class DemoApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    try (ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args)) {
      doStuff(appContext);
    }
  }

  private static void doStuff(ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext) throws InterruptedException {
    MyComponent myComponent = appContext.getBean(MyComponent.class);
    myComponent.doSomething();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    myComponent.doSomething();
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q65397019;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Arrays;

@Aspect
@Component
public class MyAspect {
  @Around("@annotation(myAnnotation)")
  public Object advice2(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, MyAnnotation myAnnotation) throws Throwable {
    if (
      Arrays.stream(new Exception().getStackTrace())
        .map(StackTraceElement::toString)
        .anyMatch(string -> string.contains("scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run("))
    )
      System.out.println(joinPoint + " -> scheduled");
    else
      System.out.println(joinPoint + " -> normal");
    return joinPoint.proceed();
  }
}
```

This will print something like:

```
(...)
2020-12-22 10:00:59.372  INFO 1620 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
execution(void de.scrum_master.spring.q65397019.MyComponent.doSomething()) -> scheduled
2020-12-22 10:00:59.456  INFO 1620 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-12-22 10:00:59.456  INFO 1620 --- [           main] d.s.spring.q65397019.DemoApplication     : Started DemoApplication in 6.534 seconds (JVM running for 8.329)
execution(void de.scrum_master.spring.q65397019.MyComponent.doSomething()) -> normal
execution(void de.scrum_master.spring.q65397019.MyComponent.doSomething()) -> scheduled
execution(void de.scrum_master.spring.q65397019.MyComponent.doSomething()) -> normal
2020-12-22 10:01:00.475  INFO 1620 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2020-12-22 10:01:00.477  INFO 1620 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
(...)
```

On Java 9+ you could use the stack walking API which would be more efficient than creating full stack traces from exception instances or querying them from the currently running thread.

**Caveat:** If you also annotate your scheduled method with `@Async`, then this will not work anymore because then the asynchronously running method does not have a stack trace in which you could identify that it was triggered by a `ScheduledMethodRunnable` or an application class.